# How do I find the current .sqlite file on the device (iPad)

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsfilemanager, magicalrecord

I need to find the current .sqlite file location for backup purposes; how do I do this?  This is the code I have, which returns "file not found":

```
//  find current directory for saori.sqlite
NSString *coreDataStorePath = [self createCoreDataStorePath];
//  sqlite store setup
NSString *storePath  = [coreDataStorePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BookstoreInventoryManager.sqlite"];  //  Application Support/SalonBook/saori.sqlite/saori.sqlite
NSLog(@"\n\nBACKUP - storePath: %@",storePath);

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: storePath])
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];  //  set stack, etc to 'nil'
else  {
    NSLog(@"\n\n-->BookstoreInventoryManager files not found");  // log message "unable to find sqlite files
    return;
}
```

Here is the code for *createCoreDataStorePath*:

```
-(NSString *)createCoreDataStorePath  {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [paths firstObject];

NSString *coreDataStorePath  = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/books"];
NSLog(@"\n\ncoreDataStorePath: %@", coreDataStorePath);

return coreDataStorePath;
```

}

I have looked at Google and SO, and didn't find my answer there.

Comment: What is `coreDataStorePath`? How do you keep/retrieve it? With `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... using this code:

```
-(NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
return basePath;
```

}

It gives me the actual URL of the store... thanks you *Larme* for your response.  SD